# coredata fetch with predicate for object relation using swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to perform a fetch for an entity in coreData.  This entity has a one to one relation with another entity.  I want to only get the items in the first entity that have a relation to a particular item in the second entity.  I'm trying this predicate which I know is incorrect:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ItemA> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemA")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemA.itemB.itemBId == %d", Int(itemB.itemBId))
```

Comment: So you want to get the item of type `itemA` whose `Id` is equal to that of `itemB`,  right?

Comment: I can get the relation itemB of itemA by subscripting itemA,itemB. I want to search all itemA's for only those whose itemB has an id of x.  so itemA.itemB.itemBID = x.

Comment: I don't want the item of type itemA whose Id is equal to that of itemB.  I want the items of type itemA whose relation itemB has an id of itemBId,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using `itemA.itemB.itemBId` , here you are using a new entity of itemA , where as you dont need to give its name, since this predicate will be applied on `itemA` entity, so either you can use only `itemB.itemBId` inside predicate or you can use `SELF.itemB.itemBId` (I am not sure about SELF or self, obviously you can look it up).

So I think you can get the items of type `itemA` whose relation `itemB` has an id of `itemBId` like this:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ItemA> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemA")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemB.itemBId == %d", Int(itemB.itemBId))
```

Comment: thanks very much.  I had that redundant itemA that was messing it up.